# Automatic copying of files into output folder with Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have the following situation:

- A solution containing two projects, namely `A` and `B`;
- Project `B` is the final executable and depends on `A`;
- `A` has dependencies on some files which I ensure are copied into the output folder of `A` by:

  - Selecting `Show All Files` in Solution Explorer;
  - Right-clicking on the file and selecting `Include in Project`;
  - In the Properties page, selecting `Copy if newer` for `Copy to output directory`.

When building `B`, the assembly corresponding to `A` is copied into the output folder, as well as any assemblies that are referenced by `A`.  That said, how do I get all the other dependent files copied over to the `B` output folder *without* including explicit references to the same in `B`?

Comment: Quick and dirty hack: put an xcopy command in the post build step of B.

Comment: @slugster, it's hacks like that which I'd like to avoid--xcopy is what I've been using up until now; just wondering if VS has it in it to be smarter than that.

Comment: I've done a fair amount of messing with project files and settings over the years, and AFAIK there's no way you'll achieve this without either directly including the files as part of the project's contents, or by writing a post build script. If you do use the post build script xcopy has some power, you can also use path macros and wildcards.

Comment: @slugster - yes, I suppose that was wishful thinking.  I'll use a solution like that, as ugly as it is.

Comment: Glad you found a fix - you should put that as your answer (then mark it).

Comment: Actually, turns out I was mistaken - the files still don't get copied over, so this is a genuine issue in my book.